# Trying to load opserver

Tags: vb.net, opserver

I downloaded opserver that I saw at SQLPass.  I can't seem to do anything with it.  I tried opening it with VS 2008, VS 2010 and keep getting incompatible errors.  What version of VS should I be using?  I am a newbie so am in real unfamiliar territory.  What do I do after I download it?  Are there step by step instructions anywhere?

Comment: I think the minimum version is VS2012. Just a few days ago there was an update to the repo that pushed it to VS2013, but you could probably get around that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Opserver targets ASP.NET 4.5 for concurrency features, which I believe requires 2012 or better.

The official Opserver documentation assumes that you know how to build and publish and ASP.NET MVC 4 application. Typically the challenge in building MVC is getting the right dependencies/config setup on IIS the first time. Very easy to update after that. There are many blog posts and good answers on this site on that general subject.

If you want directions specific to Opserver, currently you are limited to third party blog posts such as the following:

- [Patrick Hyatt: Setting Up StackExchange's Opserver](http://www.patrickhyatt.com/2013/10/25/setting-up-stackexchanges-opserver.html) (very useful for the config files)
- [Danny Sorensen: Using Opserver Will It Build?](http://dannysorensen.azurewebsites.net/2013/11/using-stack-exchanges-opserver-step-1-will-it-build/) (my own experience so far)

If this is not familiar territory, I recommend the following:

1. Use Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 on a machine with ASP.NET 4.5
2. Only enable the Opserver security file. Modify it for your IP address, or use "alladmin" to start.
3. Build it. If it doesn't work, use StackOverflow to solve your issue. You're having trouble with ASP.NET MVC 4, not Opserver at this point.
4. Now enable one additional config file at a time and build it again until you are done. Note, that you will not need to enable all of the config files unless your setup matches that of StackOverflow. Most of the config files are intended to be optional and left disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good with 2010, but you need to have [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) installed before opening the solution and building.